# Create a generic Json serialization function

Tags: json, scala, generics, playframework, playframework-2.2

Is it possible to create a generic function in Scala, using Play Framework 2.2, that will serialize an arbitrary object to JSON, without having to be supplied a writer or formatter?

For instance, this non-generic code will create a JSON response given a Customer:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Customer(id: Int, name: String)

object scratch {
  val p = Customer(1, "n")                        
  //> p  : Customer = Customer(1,n)

  def createJsonResponseCustomer(data: Customer) = {
    implicit val formatter = Json.format[Customer]
    Json.obj("success" -> true, "data" -> Json.toJson[Customer](data))
  }

  createJsonResponseCustomer(p)                   
  //> res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"success":true,"data":{"id":1,"name":"n"}}
}
```

To avoid having to define the formatter for each different object, I'd like to create a generic function like this:

```
def createJsonResponse[T](data: T) = {
  implicit val formatter = Json.format[T]
  Json.obj("success" -> true, "data" -> Json.toJson[T](data))
}
```

But this attempt produces the error `No unapply function found` at `Json.format[T]`.

In other words, this works:

```
def getFormatter(c: Customer) = Json.format[Customer]
```

but this doesn't:

```
def getFormatterGeneric[T](c: T) = Json.format[T]
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define the formatter somewhere, for each type you wish to read or write. This is because the formatter instances are resolved at compile time, not at runtime. *This is a good thing*, because it means trying to serialize a type that does not have a serializer becomes a compile-time error, not a runtime one.

Instead of defining the formatters on the fly, define them in a module that you can reuse, e.g.

```
object JsonFormatters {
  implicit val customerWrites: Format[Customer] = Json.format[Customer]
}
```

Then `import JsonFormatters._` in the scope that you want to write some JSON.

Now, you can write a generic method similar to what you wanted: you just have to specify the requirement for a formatter in the signature of your method. In practice, this is an implicit paramter of type `Writes[T]`.

```
def createJsonResponse[T](data: T)(implicit writes: Writes[T]) =
  Json.obj("success" -> true, "data" -> Json.toJson[T](data))
```

You can also write this method signature using context bound syntax, i.e.

```
def createJsonResponse[T : Writes](data: T) = ...
```

This requires that there is an instance of `Writes[T]` in scope; but the compiler will choose the correct instance for you based on the type `T`, rather than you resolving it explicitly.

Note that `Writes[T]` is a supertype of `Format[T]`; since you are only *writing* JSON in this method, there's no need to specify a requirement for `Format[T]`, which would also give you `Reads[T]`.

Comment: It might be nice to add that you can just create a `Writes[T]` automatically: `implicit blahWrites = Json.Writes[Blah]` ([link to docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception)).

Comment: Yes, the reason you can't do it once and for all for all types is because `Json.format` is a _macro_ which _looks at the specific type_ and generates some _type-specific_ code for it. It obviously can't do that to a type parameter.

Comment: Can you please give a full example of doing it in play 2.8? I tested this but no luck :( I want to create a single function to serialize any time.