# Cannot resolve Writes[T] at compile time in Play Json

Tags: scala, reflection, play-json

I am trying to make a generic Writer to get me the String representation of a json with Play Json. What I've got till now is

```
import com.twitter.finatra.http.Controller
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Writes}

trait MyController extends Controller {
  def handle(request: AnyRef) =
    response
     .ok
     .json(createJsonResponse(manage(request)))
     .toFuture

   def manage[T : Writes](request: AnyRef): T

  // There should be an implicit Writes[T] in scope
   def createJsonResponse[T : Writes](data: T) = Json.stringify(Json.toJson[T](data))
}
```

I have  `case class TotalsForResponse(issuer: String, total: Int)` defined and

```
  object JsonFormatters {
   implicit val totalsForResponseWrites = Json.format[TotalsForResponse]
  }
```

This should provide me at compile with an implicit Writes[T] in scope. IN one of my controllers I have

```
def manage[T : Writes](request: AnyRef) = request match {

case TotalInvestorsForRequest(issuer) =>
  TotalsForResponse(issuer,
    TitleSectionDBHandler.totalInvestorsFor(issuer))
  .asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

which results in `diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes[Nothing]`
 at compile time. This was taken from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611361/create-a-generic-json-serialization-function) which I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: How an implicit resolution error can occur at runtime?

Comment: Corrected that to 'compile' thanks!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code you posted in which generic type `T` is actualised (I mean a concrete type is given as the generic type `T`). The whole code seems a bit weird to me, not sure what you want to achieve but I would first make sure that `Json.toJson[TotalsForResponse]` compiles successfully.

Comment: Hi Nader, `Json.toJson(TotalsForResponse(issuer, total))` does compile successfully in the manage function, but not at MyController scope, although I'm importing the JsonFormatters correctly inside, type T would be any type defining a Writes[T] over there.

Comment: @TomasDuhourq did you get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked, you forgot to add `import JsonFormatters._` to bring the `Format[T]` into scope.

Comment: imported them, still getting the same error at compile time